# how to disable permalink on my custom tag in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

[enter image description here][1]
1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWylj.png
I Did a post with some content and two a tags (quick view and download) with custom URL. **when I enable the permalink by post name then my URL not found in the category page.  please help me.

**this is my website** URL https://w3codemasters.in

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's a little difficult to understand.

Comment: open this URL  https://w3codemasters.in/latest-jquery-plugins/ and click quick view button then you will see my URL not open coz of the permalink.